# Difficulty With Atlas API On Unity

Tags: unity, mongodb

I can't figure out how to post/get to the API in Unity. I was using the Mongo Driver before, but that seems to not work on UWP (I guess?) So I'm trying to get the Atlas API set up, but I can't figure out how to call it.

```
IEnumerator Test()
{
    ActivationCode code = new ActivationCode();
    code.code = "Test";

    string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(code);

    string url = "https://ap-southeast-1.aws.data.mongodb-api.com/app/data-mgiig/endpoint/data/v1/action/insertOne";
            
    UnityWebRequest request = new UnityWebRequest(url, "POST");
    json = "{\"database\":\"ActivationCodes\",\"collection\":\"ActivationCode\"," + json + "}";
    request.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

    request.SetRequestHeader("api-key", "....");

    byte[] bodyRaw = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
    request.uploadHandler = new UploadHandlerRaw(bodyRaw);

    yield return request.SendWebRequest();
    print(request.error);

}
```

[Pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/MM56iSUP)

This is my code... The logs in Atlas API are giving "OK", but Unity is giving me a 400 error. I just made this as a test to try and get the API all set up. (Don't worry, I left the API key in, but will make a new one after.)

I'm guessing the API key is being set properly, as the request is going through. Maybe it has something to do with me adding the JSON weirdly, but I don't know how the syntax is supposed to be. I'm assuming this is a simple fix, it's calling the API, it's returning "OK" in the MongoDB logs, but I'm getting a 400 error.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Are you sure your json is correctly formatted? You have 2 pairs and a single value.

Comment: @Zibelas What do you mean? Oh, if you're saying because I got "ActivationCode" twice, it's because the database is called ActivationCodes and the collection is called "ActivationCode"

Comment: @Zibelas just tested by making the json a single class(instead of manually adding all the /s and ,s) that contains an activation code, so it contains a database and collection and i'm just converting it to one json. Still getting the 400 error.

Comment: Can you share the full JSON you're sending (with any private data/API keys replaced with a placeholder, naturally)?

Comment: @DMGregory Well, here's another pastebin with just the json copied, it's not very big, i'm passing the api key in a header, not in the json. https://pastebin.com/pb4pA2A7 . I don't think there's any valuable info in there(just realized for some reason it's not turning the activation code to json, but it should still be uploading the json?)

Comment: Why use a separate pastebin instead of adding the JSON to your question? The JSON you linked does not appear to match the code above. It contains a "json" key that your string construction does not add. Can you explain this?

Comment: @DMGregory because It's not important(the second comment i made says I changed the way I was converting the json, but both have the same error) the method in the above question is the same thing but instead of converting it to json i was manually typing the json out. 

Regardless, both methods give the same error, 400.

Comment: A 400 error code means, you have a bad request. The json you have in this code is not fully shown and the most likely error source. How do you know it is not important when you as well do not know what the error is?

Comment: @Zibelas I did show the full code. The code in my original post gives a 400 error. I changed it to pass in the json a few comments ago, the one in the pastebin, instead of the one in the original post's code, and it's giving a 400 error all the same. https://imgur.com/a/LoRZKsJ this is my new code, as you can see it's practically the same, just instead of manually formatting the json with the /s and ,s, im converting a new class to json.

Comment: I'm aware 400 code means bad request, i'm trying to figure out why it's a bad request.

Comment: @Makineko you did NOT include a full json. The json in your question has a string json in it that uses an object and we have no idea how that translates in the end. A full json example in the question should include the actual element after your `\"ActivationCode\","` and not the variable json.

Comment: @Zibelas {"database":"ActivationCodes","collection":"ActivationCodes","json":{}} is the full json, the Activation code is called "json". I mentioned this in the comment before, i said "(just realized for some reason it's not parsing the activation code to json, but it should still be uploading the(blank) json?). Like, logically, this should still upload the empty activation code "json" to the ActivationCodes>Activationcode, right?

Comment: Is ActivationCode marked as [System.Serializable]?